# Axios request response is showing html instead of data

Tags: reactjs, laravel

My Code

```
 axios.post('api/sign-up', {
        name, username, sex,email, password,  mobile_number, dob
    }).then(response=> {
        this.setState({err: false});
        console.log(response.data)
    }).catch(error=> {
        this.refs.name.value="";
        this.refs.username.value="";
        this.refs.password.value="";
        this.refs.sex.value="";
        this.refs.email.value="";
        this.refs.mobile_number.value="";
        this.refs.dob.value="";
        this.setState({err: true});
    });
```

Api Route

```
Route::post('/sign-up',  [App\Http\Controllers\Api\ApiAuthController::class, 'register']);
```

It does not show any error but gives html in response. Is there any issue with axios? Please help

Comment: Hi, interesting, does it show an error?

Comment: No it does not show any error but it returns html

Comment: I can show you the screenshot if you want

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
Accept:application/json
```

to the request's header.